# How can I fetch data from two unrelated tables in one query in one row

Tags: mysql

I know that the **union** can be used to return unrelated data from two tables but it returns multiple rows and the number of columns have to match.  And there are many posts that show how.

BUT

Is there a way I can fetch unrelated fields from two tables in **one row** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this

```
select (select country from country  where country_ref =1) country,
(select user_name from users where user_ref = 1) user
```

The columns/fields can be of any type.